# Word 2013- VBA- How To Add Punctuation to Results From A User Form List Box?

Tags: vba, list, ms-word, combobox, userform

I have a user form with list box (multi selection) with four entries.

[image]

The following code builds the string:

```
Dim myArray() As String
'Use Split function to return a zero based one dimensional array.
    myArray = Split("text 1|" _
            & "text 2|" _
            & "text 3|" _
            & "text 4", "|")
  'Use .List method to populate listbox.
  ListBox1.List = myArray
  'Use the .ColumnWidth property to set column widths.  0 results in a hidden column.
  ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "1"
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
```

The following code below successfully inserts any combination of the four selected entries with a `,`  and space in between each entry including a `.` at the end i.e. `text 1, .` or `text 1, text 2, text 3, .` or `text 1, text 2, text 3, text 4, .` into a content control.

```
Dim SelectedTexts As String
Dim index As Long
    For index = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
            'Adds comma after every entry
            SelectedTexts = SelectedTexts & ListBox1.List(index) & ", "
        End If
    Next
    'Adds period to the end
    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("test").Item(1).Range.Text = Mid(SelectedTexts, 1) _
    & "."
Unload Me

lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
Me.Repaint
Me.Hide
```

I am trying to accomplish two things:

1. I only want a `.` after the last entry i.e. `text 1.`  NOT `text 1, .`
2. I want there to be an `and` before the last result i.e. `text 1 and text 2.` or `text 1, text 2 and text 3.` or `text 1, text 2 and text 4.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your string is built, you need to manipulate it into the form you require.  Here is the logic to do this:

```
Private Sub Test()
   Dim SelectedTexts As String
   Dim index As Long
   
   For index = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
      If ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
         SelectedTexts = SelectedTexts & ListBox1.List(index) & ", "
      End If
   Next

   SelectedTexts = Mid(SelectedTexts, 1, Len(SelectedTexts) - 2) & "."
   index = InStrRev(SelectedTexts, ",")
   If index > 0 Then SelectedTexts = Left(SelectedTexts, index - 1) & " and " & Right(SelectedTexts, Len(SelectedTexts) - index - 1)

   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("test").Item(1).Range.Text = SelectedTexts
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am having difficulty figuring out how to adapt your code to mine.

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche I updated the answer to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Thank you sir.  I updated my question and included how I built the string from the listbox because I am still struggling over here.  Can't seem to figure it out still.  My brain feels like gel from looking at this so long.

Comment: Unless I am not understanding something, if you select the first 3 items in the listbox your string would be like I show above.  If you run this example, it formats correctly along with every other combination I have tried.  What exactly is your issue?

Comment: When I inserted my code to build the string from a list box where you indicated, ```text 1, text 2 and text 3.``` would result no matter what I selected from the list box.  @Ricardo Diaz provided working solution.  Still trying to figure out what the disconnect is with your code.

Comment: The line `SelectedTexts = "text 1, text 2, text 3, "` was for my testing instead of building it from a listbox.  Replace that line with your logic to build the string.  It's the last 4 lines of code that are important.

Comment: Wow....whaddya know.  Right over my head.  I figured it out and updated your answer with my code to build the string.  It works now.  Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Adjusted case order

EDIT 2: Recfactored code

```
    Dim SelectedTexts As String
    Dim index As Long
    
    
    ' Get total selected
    Dim totalSelected As Long
    For index = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
            totalSelected = totalSelected + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Convert total selected to base 0
    totalSelected = totalSelected - 1
    
    Dim counter As Long
    
    For index = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
            'Adds comma after every entry
            Dim delimiter As String
            Select Case True
                Case counter = totalSelected - 1
                delimiter = " and "
                Case counter < totalSelected
                delimiter = ", "
                Case Else
                delimiter = ""
                End Select
            SelectedTexts = SelectedTexts & ListBox1.List(index) & delimiter
            
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    'Adds period to the end
    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("test").Item(1).Range.Text = Mid(SelectedTexts, 1) _
    & "."
    Unload Me
    
lbl_Exit:
      Exit Sub
    Me.Repaint
    Me.Hide
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but based on your code above, the desired result only occurs if I select the following combinations: ```text 4.```, ```text 3 and text 4.```, ```text 1, text 3 and text 4.``` or ```text 2, text 3 and text 4.```.  Any other combination is incorrect and all over the place.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a screenshot of the listbox

Comment: I edited the question and added a screenshot of the listbox

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche Got it. Please use the updated code

Comment: Thank you so very much sir!  Your code does the trick!

Comment: Answer below by @Brian M Stafford also works too.  Thank you both so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Simply change:

```
'Adds period to the end
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("test").Item(1).Range.Text = Mid(SelectedTexts, 1) _
& "."
```

to:

```
'Adds "and", plus period to the end
SelectedTexts = Left(SelectedTexts, Len(SelectedTexts) - 2) & "."
SelectedTexts = Left(SelectedTexts, InStrRev(SelectedTexts, ",") - 1) & ", and " & _
  Right(SelectedTexts, Len(SelectedTexts) - InStrRev(SelectedTexts, ",") - 1)
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("test").Item(1).Range.Text = SelectedTexts
```

If you don't want the comma before the 'and', change ", and " to " and ".

Comment: This adds ```, and``` to end no matter what combination is selected.