# How To Populate Selections From A User Form List Box into Bullets MS-Word-VBA?

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, ms-word

EDITED

Referring to a question I asked previously [Word 2013- VBA- How To Add Punctuation to Results From A User Form List Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618745/word-2013-vba-how-to-add-punctuation-to-results-from-a-user-form-list-box/65620698?noredirect=1#comment116046997_65620698), how would I change the following code to populate the results in a bullet format instead of commas?

```
Private Sub Test()
   Dim SelectedTexts As String
   Dim index As Long
   
   For index = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
      If ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
         SelectedTexts = SelectedTexts & ListBox1.List(index) & ", "
      End If
   Next

   SelectedTexts = Mid(SelectedTexts, 1, Len(SelectedTexts) - 2) & "."
   index = InStrRev(SelectedTexts, ",")
   If index > 0 Then SelectedTexts = Left(SelectedTexts, index - 1) & " and " & Right(SelectedTexts, Len(SelectedTexts) - index - 1)

   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("test").Item(1).Range.Text = SelectedTexts
End Sub
```

Comment: " Furthermore, as I insert more drop down lists and make selection(s), it should remove that item from all previous existing lists to prevent duplicate selection." this is not a possible scenario based on your plan to remove already-selected items from lists inserted later.

Comment: You can improve your question by showing your code and explaining what you have already tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   *Does Greg Maxey's page help?* https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_magic_dropdowns.html If not, what problems are you running into?  See also: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/44436-needing-learn-dependent-drop-downs-how-keep.html

Comment: @ Charles Kenyon and @ Tim Williams- thank you for both your feedback.  See my edited question please

Comment: This is a completely different question to the original, ***not*** an edit. In future please ask a new question rather than completely changing an existing one that already has replies.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt- Yes sir.  Link to proper question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176847/how-to-populate-selections-from-a-user-form-list-box-into-bullets-ms-word-vba-p

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial undertaking. One wonders whether you even tried to modify your existing code. The whole lot could be done with your existing content control if you apply a suitable bullet format to it. For example:

```
Private Sub Test()
   Dim SelectedTexts As String
   Dim index As Long
   
   For index = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
      If ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
         SelectedTexts = SelectedTexts & ListBox1.List(index) & ";" & vbCr
      End If
   Next

   SelectedTexts = Mid(SelectedTexts, 1, Len(SelectedTexts) - 2) & "."
   index = InStrRev(SelectedTexts, vbCr)
   If index > 0 Then SelectedTexts = Left(SelectedTexts, index - 1) & " and " & Right(SelectedTexts, Len(SelectedTexts) - index + 1)

   ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("test").Item(1).Range.Text = SelectedTexts
End Sub
```

Comment: Per @Timothy Rylatt, Link to proper question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176847/how-to-populate-selections-from-a-user-form-list-box-into-bullets-ms-word-vba-p

Comment: Why are you asking the same question I've already answered?

Comment: Sir, I was following Timothy Rylatt's guidance above