# How To Populate Selections From A User Form List Box into Bullets?

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, ms-word

The following code takes any combination of the selected text from the list box and adds a bullet as shown:

```
Dim SelectedTexts As String
Dim index As Long

    For index = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
         
            SelectedTexts = SelectedTexts & ListBox1.List(index) & " "
        End If
    Next
        Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior

    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Test").Item(1) _
    .Range.Text = SelectedTexts
Unload Me

lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
Me.Repaint
Me.Hide
```

[image]

QUESTION:  How do I populate the selected text from the list box as shown below?

[image]

Comment: `SelectedTexts = SelectedTexts & ListBox1.List(index) & vbNewLine`

Comment: That works!  However this causes there to always be an empty bullet at the end of the list.

Comment: Ahh, yeah if you do an `if selectedtexts = ""` and move `vbnewline` so its `SelectedTexts = SelectedTexts & vbnewline & ListBox1.List(index)` You can avoid that. So the `if` has no `vbnewline` and the `else` does.

Comment: Like this?

```If ListBox1.Selected(index) Then```
    ```SelectedTexts = ""```
    ```Else```
    ```SelectedTexts = SelectedTexts & vbNewLine & ListBox1.List(index)```
```End If```

Comment: Not quite, that would skip your first selection, I posted an answer that has it.

Comment: This is a **duplicate** of a question I answered this *in full* nearly two weeks ago in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998040/how-to-populate-selections-from-a-user-form-list-box-into-bullets-ms-word-vba/66001584?noredirect=1#comment116997516_66001584 !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Dim SelectedTexts As String
Dim index As Long

    For index = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(index) Then
            If SelectedTexts = "" Then
                SelectedTexts = ListBox1.List(index)
            Else
                SelectedTexts = SelectedTexts & vbNewLine & ListBox1.List(index)
            End If
        End If
    Next
        Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior

    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Test").Item(1) _
    .Range.Text = SelectedTexts
Unload Me

lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
Me.Repaint
Me.Hide
```